# Autowire Bean with no default constructor, using config annotation

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I have this Repository class which I wish to Autowire in a unit test. I'm currently getting the "no default constructor" error when running the test.

The class in question has no default constructor, I'm new to spring so may not have created the Bean correctly in the config class.

Below is the Bean in question (has no default constructor)

```
@Repository
public class GenericDaoImpl<T extends AbstractEntity> implements GenericDao<T> {
```

The config class

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example")
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    GenericDaoImpl<AbstractEntity> genericDoaIpm(final Class<AbstractEntity> tClass) {
        return new GenericDaoImpl<AbstractEntity>(tClass);
    }
}
```

And in the test I have:

```
@Autowired
private GenericDaoImpl<AbstractEntity> genericDaoImpl;
```

Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/44423-autowire-constructor) and [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_autowired_annotation.htm), you only need to mark your constructor with `@Autowired`.

**GenericDaoImpl.java**

```
@Autowired
public GenericDaoImpl(Class<?> tClass) {
    ...
}
```

> You can apply @Autowired to constructors as well. A constructor @Autowired annotation indicates that the constructor should be autowired when creating the bean, even if no  elements are used while configuring the bean in XML file

Comment: This only applies to beans that have a default constructor, mine does not, hence more is required.

Comment: I'm not sure you understood me, I've added an example just in case

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to work, but now I have the issue of not being able to autowire a bean of type java.lang.class.
But that's a different issue.